# Why did Pablo say, "The flirty grip"?

Tags: plot-explanation, marriage-story

Pablo met Nicole second time at halloween party:

> Pablo: Oh, hey, Pablo. Uh, we met at...
>
> Nicole: You held the bounce board.
>
> Pablo: **The flirty grip**.

Why did Pablo say, "The flirty grip"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [**grip**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grip_(job)) is a worker on a film set who is works with (among other things) the lighting for a scene.  A [bounce board](https://www.exposureguide.com/board-reflectors/) is a large piece of white or metallic cloth or board that reflects a diffuse light onto the scene being photographed.

So Pablo is reminding Nicole that he was a grip on the film set (?) where they first met, and that he was specifically the grip who was holding the bounce board.  (And that he was flirting with her on that occasion.)